# Swift3 project involving JSON parsing and both static and dynamic UITableView cells - making it more object-oriented

Tags: ios, iphone, json, uitableview, swift3

I have a CTA (Chicago Transit Authority) train tracking app that executes and works exactly as I want it to. However, the code itself is far from object-oriented.

You can choose which line you want, which brings you to a station screen that shows all the stations, which you can click on to get to a TableView that shows train arrival times for each station and the destination train station with data pull from a JSON file that CTA maintains.

However, I had to create a new tableView swift file for each train station, resulting in a huge number of tableViews. If I ever need to change something, I would need to copy and paste that change into all the station tableViews.

I think one reason for this is I used static cells for the Trains tableView and the Stations tableViews except the tableViews for each destination station which are dynamic (I did this because the stations never change but the information for the Destination stations is updated frequently for the trains arriving. Also, I couldn't figure out how to change the JSON feed being sent from the stations tableView to the Destination station tableView so that each destination station parses a different JSON file when I did try to make the project mostly dynamic tableView cells).

Is there a way to make it so I can have only one dynamic cell tableView for the Stations tableView (e.g. Red Line Stations tableView only has one dynamic prototype cell)?

Below is my project storyboard and the code for it:

[image]

```
import UIKit

class RedHowardTableViewController: UITableViewController {

class Destinations {
    var destination: String = ""
    var time: String = ""
}

var feed = "http://lapi.transitchicago.com/api/1.0/ttarrivals.aspx?key=mykey&mapid=40900&outputType=JSON"

var dataAvailable = false

var records = [Destinations]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    parseData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    for r in records {
        r.time = ""
        r.destination = ""
    }
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataAvailable ? records.count : 15
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if (dataAvailable) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let destinationRow = records[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Heading towards " + destinationRow.destination
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Arriving at: " +  destinationRow.time
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlaceholderCell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}

func parseData() {
    guard let feedURL = URL(string: feed) else {
        return
    }
    let request = URLRequest(url: feedURL)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {(data, response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("Error")
        }
        else {
            if let content = data {

                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: []) as? [String:Any] ?? [:]
                    print(json)
                    if let ctattimetable = json["ctatt"] as? [String:Any] {
                        if let estArrivalTime = ctattimetable["eta"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                            for item in estArrivalTime{

                                if let headingTowards = item["destNm"] as? String,
                                    let arrivalTime = item["arrT"] as? String {
                                    if (headingTowards != "Howard") {
                                        let record = Destinations()
                                        record.destination = headingTowards
                                        let formattedDate = String(arrivalTime.characters.suffix(8))
                                        let components = formattedDate.components(separatedBy: ":").flatMap({Int($0)})
                                        let time12h = String(format: "%d:%02d", components[0] % 12, components[1]) + (components[0] < 12 ? "am" : "pm")
                                        record.time = String(time12h)
                                        self.records.append(record)
                                    }
                                }
                                self.dataAvailable = true
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch { 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
}
```

Below is what I had when I tried to do this mostly with dynamic tableViews, which resulted in the same JSON file being parsed for each Destination tableView:

TableViewController for all the Blue Line stations below:

```
import UIKit

class BlueLineTableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return bluelinestations.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bluelinecell", for: indexPath)
    let station = bluelinestations[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = station.name
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: station.image)
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let row = indexPath.row
    if row == 0 {
        BlueBelmontTableViewController().feed = "http://lapi.transitchicago.com/api/1.0/ttarrivals.aspx?key=mykey&mapid=40890&outputType=JSON"
    }
    if row == 1   {
        BlueBelmontTableViewController().feed="http://lapi.transitchicago.com/api/1.0/ttarrivals.aspx?key=mykey&mapid=40820&outputType=JSON"
    }   
}
}
```

The code for the Destination Station tableViewController showing the arrival times for each station

```
import UIKit

class BlueBelmontTableViewController: UITableViewController {

class Destinations {
    var destination: String = ""
    var time: String = ""
}

var feed = "http://lapi.transitchicago.com/api/1.0/ttarrivals.aspx?key=mykey&mapid=40440&outputType=JSON"
var dataAvailable = false
var records = [Destinations]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    parseData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    for r in records {
        r.time = ""
        r.destination = ""
    }
}
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataAvailable ? records.count : 15
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if (dataAvailable) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) 
        let destinationRow = records[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = destinationRow.destination
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = destinationRow.time
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlaceholderCell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}

func parseData() {
    guard let feedURL = URL(string: feed) else {
        return
    }
    let request = URLRequest(url: feedURL)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {(data, response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("Error")
        }
        else {
            if let content = data {

                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: []) as? [String:Any] ?? [:]
                    print(json)

                    if let ctattimetable = json["ctatt"] as? [String:Any] {
                        if let estArrivalTime = ctattimetable["eta"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                            for item in estArrivalTime{
                                if let headingTowards = item["destNm"] as? String,
                                    let arrivalTime = item["arrT"] as? String {
                                    let record = Destinations()
                                    record.destination = headingTowards
                                    record.time = arrivalTime
                                    self.records.append(record)
                                }
                                self.dataAvailable = true
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch {
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you used static cell, so when you define an action for cell selection event, have many segue as static cell you have, a segue will correspond with a table view, therefore you'll have many table view to control in your storyboard.

I think you should change your `Train Table View` and `Station Table View` both to dynamic. It reduce a lot of table and easily to change and edit. It'll more flexible.

Like this:
[image]

**EDIT: pass data for destination controller of a segue**

In your `Station View Controller`, add this segue delegate function:

```
// MARK: - segue perform handle

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

    guard let segueIdentifier = segue.identifier else {
        return
    }

    switch segueIdentifier {
    case "your_segue_identifer":
        let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? DestinationViewController
        guard let selectedRowIndex = yourTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row else {
            break
        }

        destinationViewController?.config(withStation station: yourStationList[selectedRowIndex])
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to make it work dynamically. I edited the Blue Line stations code above (see the last method) but I can't seem to get it to pass the feed to the Destination View Controller. Do you know how I would go about setting the feed variable to a new url string (in the Destination View Controller code) depending on which row was clicked?

Comment: Check my edited answer, i added code block to pass feed to the Destination View Controller.